# SQL query to count in group by with specific condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My table data:

```
id      fieldId  Name   Text
----    ------  -----   ----
1        101    name1   a1
2        102    name2   a2
3        101    name1   a1
4        103    name3   a2
5        102    name2   a3
6        101    name1   c1
7        101    name1   a3
8        102    name2   
9        101    name1   b2
10       103    name3   c1
```

I need output like

```
Name    Count(fieldId)  Count_id_text_is_either_a1_or_a2_a3
------      ------        -------
name1   4                   2
name2   3                   2
name3   2                   1
```

- `Name` = I need to group by fieldId.
- `Count(fieldId)` = Count each group records.
- `Count_id_text_is_either_a1_or_a2_a3` = This is the column I want the count of records of group only if `Text like 'a1-%' or 'a2-%' or 'a3-%'`.

Can this be done by single query? If yes the please explain how? If no then what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Your data sample consists of 10 rows, but the total of `Count(fieldId)` in the expected output is 9. More specifically, it's `name1` that seems miscounted: there are 5 entries in total, and 3 contain `a...` values, but you've shown, accordingly, 4 and 2. Do you only need to count *distinct* `Text` values, perhaps? (in both cases?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select Name, 
    count(*) as CountAll, 
    count(case when Text like 'a1-%' or Text like 'a2-%' or Text like 'a3-%' then 1 end) as CountA1A2A3
from MyTable
group by Name
```

You could also use a RegEx if you wish.

Comment: That the correct answer. +1 but I forget to say that i need co compare fieldID by like operator also... can you help in that...? see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Here.

```
SELECT
    `Name`,
    COUNT(*) AS 'fieldId',
    COUNT(IF(`Text` REGEXP '^a[1-3]',1,NULL)) AS 'a1a2a3'
FROM (SELECT * FROM `items` GROUP BY `Name`,`Text`) t1
GROUP BY `Name`;
```